# Java: while loop with self-contain counter

Tags: java, loops, while-loop, counter

I want to ask if there are any way that you can write a while loop in Java that has the main counter inside the loop as well, that is when you exit the loop, the counter variable will also be destroyed.

For example, when we exit this loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    //do something
}
```

the variable i is destroyed as well, thus keeping the code clean.

But for a `while` loop, we must create a counter variable outside the loop itself; so, when the loop exits, the counter variable still exists in the main program.

```
int counter = 0;
while (counter < 10) {
     counter++;
}
counter--; //we can still manipulate the counter variable here
```

What I want to ask is: is there some way to put the counter variable inside the `while` loop itself, such as:

```
while ( (int i = 0) < 10 ) {
    counter++;
}
```

Comment: Why is it important to "destroy" the counter?  In what way is this "clean"?

Comment: Well, that's the for loop. What's wrong with it?

Comment: @ScottHunter The counter may be accidentally modified later and can create a bug or if you have a lot of while loops and counters, the namespace will be quite messy. But mostly I just want it to be clean.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can put `{` and `}` around the `int counter` and `while` loop.

```
{
  int counter = 0;
  while (counter < 10) {
    counter++;
  }
}
// counter is inaccessible here
```

But this is really a lot messier than just using a for loop.

Comment: Thank you, nice to know that is possible. And sure it is a lot messier than just a for loop, that might be why I haven't seen it used before.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you have to use "external" counter.